# UItableViewCell setTextColor deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to change the text color in the `UITableViewCell` using `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` as its for a theme in my app.

Here's the line of code:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[SearchTableView class]]] setTextColor:snackOrangeColor];
```

This works. But setTextColor is was deprecated in iOS 3.0. Hence, I can't use it. I couldn't find a proper solution for this yet.

My question is what should I use to change text color in UITableViewCell in place of setTextColor?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the cell's textLabel's textColor.

```
 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor someColor];
```

or

Create a custom UITableViewCell

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CustomUITableViewCell class], nil] 
 setTextColor:[UIColor someColor]];
```

I don't think there's going to be an alternative to this. I would recommend creating the color in a constant and just calling the constant in your code.

Comment: I know about this method. But I need to use UIAppearance as I am making theme for the app.

Comment: I guess this is the only way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom class for cell, then drag and OUTlet of UILabel. Then use that custom cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @s.d. you welcome. You may found it usefull - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Answer (score 1):

For you would be correct to add "textLabel"

```
[[UITableViewCell appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[SearchTableView class]]].textLabel setTextColor:snackOrangeColor];
```